# How to style correctly input type range?

Tags: css

I came up with such a way to style the input type="range" through a linear-gradient, but when the variable is set to 75%, it is not behaving correctly, how can I fix it?

```css
body{
background: green;
}
.wrapper {
      width: 20vmin;
      }

      input {
        width: 100%;
        --litters-range: 75%;

        appearance: none;
        outline: none;
        height: 1vmin;
        border-radius: 0.5vmin;
        background: linear-gradient(
          to left,
          rgba(87, 87, 87, 0.46) calc(100% - var(--litters-range)),
          white var(--litters-range)
        );
        }
        input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
          cursor: pointer;
          appearance: none;
          width: 2vmin;
          height: 2vmin;
          background: white;
          border-radius: 50%;
        }
      
    // 25% works correctly but 75% not
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="range" />
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a mistake with your stop/start value, they could be the same and be set from left to right.

Also, you need to update that var() via javaScript, CSS cannot do it for you.

Possible example (use console.log() to check what happens) then remove or comment it):

```js
var val = document.querySelector('.wrapper input[type="range"]');
let range = val.value;

val.addEventListener("input", function() { // onchange ...
  let range = val.value + '%';
  console.log(range);
  val.style.setProperty("--litters-range", range);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 20vmin;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  --litters-range: 75%;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 1vmin;
  border-radius: 0.5vmin;
  background: linear-gradient( to right, white var(--litters-range), rgba(87, 87, 87, 0.46) var(--litters-range));
}

input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
  appearance: none;
  width: 2vmin;
  height: 2vmin;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="range" value="75" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .slidecontainer {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .slider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: #d3d3d3;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }
    
    .slider:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      width: 23px;
      height: 24px;
      border: 0;
      background-color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
      width: 23px;
      height: 24px;
      border: 0;
      background: url('contrasticon.png');
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Range Slider</h1>

  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  </div>

  <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function() {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but how can I display a strip for example white which will show that now, for example, more than half of the value